# Good use of memory

Tags: matlab

If i create a cell with 1000 matrices ( size of each matrix 800*1280), clearing each matrix after using it will speed up calculations ?

Example

```
 A=cell(1000,1);
  for i=1:1000
      A{i}=rand(800,1280);
  end
  image=A{1};
  image2=A{2}; % I will use image and image2 with other functions
  A{1}=[];
  A{2}=[];
```

**EDIT**

The real use of the cell will be like :

```
A=cell(1000,1);
parfor i=1:1000
    A{i}=function_that_creates_image(800,1280); % image with size 800*1280 px
end
for i=1:number_of_images   % number_of_images=1000 in this case
image1=A{1};
    image2=A{2};
    A{1}=[];
    A{2}=[];
    % image1 and image 2 will be used then in the next lines
    %next lines of code
end
```

I noticed that calculating components of `A` in a parfor loop is faster than calculating each component for each loop inside the for

Comment: Could you perhaps try changing `for` to `parfor` and putting this `function_that...` inside it then? Or are all images depending on each other and you cannot do that?

Comment: @zizy-archer Each result depend on the previous one, that's why I can't parallelize the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use less memory and speed up calculations, it's wiser to avoid using cells. Luckily, it's very easy in your case, since all your matrices are the same size, so you could use an ND-array.

```
A = zeros(800,1280,1000);
for k = 1:size(A,3)
   A(:,:,k) = function_that_creates_image(800,1280);
end
image = A(:,:,1);
image2 = A(:,:,2); % I will use image and image2 with other functions
```

EDIT:

If you want to further process each image, I would save them to a file within the `parfor`, so you will have 1000 .mat files at the end of the first loop:

```
parfor k = 1:number_of_images
   A = function_that_creates_image(800,1280);
   save(['images_dir\image' num2str(k) '.mat'],'A');
end
```

then you can load them as needed for processing using [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html):

```
for k = 1:number_of_images-1
    image1 = load(['images_dir\image' num2str(k) '.mat']);
    image2 = load(['images_dir\image' num2str(k+1) '.mat'];
    % do what you want with those images...
end
```

This way you only keep 2 images in memory each time, and on the next iteration they a replaced by the next images.

Comment: 10^9 doubles is 8GB of RAM, which is pretty huge. Unless you have at least ~32GB, this large matrix is not going to be useful all that often, except to simply hold data.

Comment: @EBH thank you for the answer . I was wondering why when I compile this line                                                   **save(['my_path\image' num2str(k)'.mat'],A)**                                    there is an error :    Error using save , argument must contain a character vector

Comment: @ransa, my apologies, I had a typo there, it should be `save(['images_dir\image' num2str(k) '.mat'],'A')` with single quotes on the `A`. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you fit everything in memory (you need at least 16GB to hold data and do some work on parts of it, to work on the full beast at the same time you should be having 32GB), clearing these won't change anything at all. If you don't, I would assume/hope Matlab and Windows are smart enough to optimize which chunk is held in memory and which is put on the disk, so again deleting won't help. But you might not want to rely on that.

What you can do is to have `A{i} = 'path-to-file';`, then load it in memory just for the time when needed. Why do you even need to first load all the images and then do work on them one by one? It would be much better for memory to simply have `image1 = rand(...);`, `image2 = rand(...);` in the loop itself, and reuse these `image1` and `image2`. No need to even have this `A`.

In general, tall arrays are your memory friendly solution you should be using if you want to have tons of data at the same time. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tall-arrays.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  In the real case, calculating components of A (  matrices that represent images) will be in parallel ( parfor) using a function that generates the components. Thus, it will be faster to calculate the components in parallel  and using them than calculating values of each image in a for.  Loading in memory A will not be useful because it changes in each use .  How can I use tall arrays in my case ?

Comment: @ransa For tall arrays, you can first generate A{i} like now (or like EBH is suggesting), then convert it to a tall array. At this point, MATLAB knows it doesn't need to keep it in memory unless when you require results from it. Better option is if these images are in an existing database (which is huge), and then you don't need to load them in memory in the first place. But if you have enough RAM it will be slower.